# Display Model Warnings along with errors in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate

[Simon Farrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367846/model-warnings-in-asp-net-mvc) pointed a nice way to extend MVC framework to handle warnings. My question is how to display the warnings along with model error through ValidationSummary but in different color. You can control if show property level warnings only on the summary, close to the property, or both, using ValidationSummary.